# Computer Restart Resets My Steam Downloads?

Tags: steam, pc

I am trying to download the new Batman. However with the file size being 35GB it will take me a while to download this.

The problem I am having is when I shutdown my pc the download for Batman resets back to about 5GB downloaded each time. I'm not sure if this could be due to me using a shutdown timer that I downloaded so I could leave my pc going for a few hours after I go to sleep?

I've looked at the other things posted on this forum but cant seem to find a solution.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Obviously not ideal, but is leaving your PC on and downloading overnight a possible workaround? Also, this may help: http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864977564068209606/

Comment: If you are already using a shutdown timer, can't you try to extend this time? Maybe it's not done yet, and needs more time.

Comment: Are you sure it's 'resetting' the download? By the sounds of it you're forcing Steam to shut down rather abruptly - It might simply be downloading different files this time (my understanding is that files on Steam are shared similar to a p2p system - it just downloads whatever is available at the time) without checking what sort of progress it got up to the last time. Try pausing the download and resuming it again, and try 'Verify Integrity of Game cache'. It may pick up that it's downloaded the 'missing' files

Comment: After reading the question a few times, the only question I find is "Anyone have any ideas?"  You probably should try un-installing your shutdown timer program because it seems to be terminating Steam ungracefully.  That is, it does not allow Steam to resume downloading.  I've shutdown my Steam client with my computer plenty of times and have never lost noticeable download progress.

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no such option in Steam. However, there is a petition/idea going on on the [Steam Forum](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2148771).

Something you can do, is to switch your computer off after a set amount of time. For example, if the estimated time is still two hours when you go to bed, you can make it shutdown after three hours (for security). To do this, run the following command (by pressing windows button + <kbd>R</kbd>:

```
shutdown -s -t 10800
```

the number is the number of seconds it waits before it shuts down. Cancel this timer by running `shutdown -a`. More information [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Shut-Down-Your-Computer-Automatically-After-a-While).

Comment: This is not what he's asking, you should read the question again.